# Getting the UIBarButtonItems I have added using Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I add 3 buttons to the `leftBarButtonItem` using interface builder.

How do I get these buttons from the view Controller?

I have tried that

```
NSArray * buttons = self.navigationController.navigationBar.items[0].leftBarButtonItems;
```

from `viewDidAppear` without success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store UIBarButton's into local variables, so you can instance it without accessing from array.

```
// Controller variable
private var myBarButton: UIBarButtonItem?

// Creation
myBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(.....)

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [myBarButton]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try in swift 4.X

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems
```

It gives array of left side items.

Comment: this gives me only one `UIBarButtonItem` and this is any button I have set.

Comment: @SpaceDog, Yeah, It gives you `UIBarButtonItem` bcz NavigationBar contains this type of object.

Comment: so, where are the buttons?

Comment: @SpaceDog [`UIBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem) : A button specialized for placement on a toolbar or tab bar.